# Emulate Joystick

Tags: servo, potentiometer, joystick

I am trying to automate a existing system that uses Joystick as its input to move the Motors in x&y directions. I actually want to emulate arduino to exactly do what the joystick is doing by just emulating the joystick through arduino. Joystick has 4 wires
1- 5Volt
2- Ground
3- x-axis
4- Y-axis

Actually i want arduino to map in such a way that it's only two digital pins are used to connect with joystick cable 3 & 4 and process inputs exactly in such a way that system thinks that as it is the input from the joystick. I just don't want to mess with the electronics of the existing system. That's why just trying to hack into joystick.

UPDATE: i have checked the Joystick for simple voltage and Resistance Measurements.
It seems like it is 1KOhm Pot.

Comment: what is your question? ... it is unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: what does this mean? ... `emulating the joystick through arduino`

Comment: `I actually emulate arduino` ... it is possible that you are using the wrong word `emulate`

Comment: For reading a joystick you need 2 analog inputs. You cannot get the same info from 2 digital input pins. Not possible. Is that what you wanted to ask?

Comment: I am trying to say that, i want arduino to act as the joystick and output exactly same signals as the joystick does. Actually i am trying to automate a system which takes input from the joystick and subsequently rotates the motors in that direction.

Comment: Then you need to provide the link to the joystick that you want to emulate. Is the joystick just the potentiometers for the axes or is there some additional electronics?

Comment: `Actually i am trying to automate a system which takes input from the joystick and subsequently rotates the motors in that direction` ... is that somehow relevant to the question?

Comment: `i want arduino to act as the joystick and output exactly same signals as the joystick does` ... why didn't you say this at the begining?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe "DS3502 I2C Digital 10K Potentiometer" will work. I am interested to hear if it really works as a joystick pot replacement because I have never used it.

Comment: Thank you, i am already going to use digital Pot. As per my knowledge, does digital Pot also Acts as a DAC. correct me of i am wrong please.

Comment: But i will be using two channel digital pot that is MAX5392

Answer (score 2):

Based on your wiring information, this looks like an analog joystick. You specified using two digital output pins to emulate the joystick to the target device.

The way to do this is to use PWM and a simple resistor-capacitor filter to convert the digital output to an analog 0-5v signal.

[Here](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/muhammad-aqib/arduino-pwm-tutorial-ae9d71) is some information about PWM:

> Arduino and PWM The Arduino IDE has a built in function
> “analogWrite()” which can be used to generate a PWM signal. The
> frequency of this generated signal for most pins will be about 490Hz
> and we can give the value from 0-255 using this function.
>
> analogWrite(0) means a signal of 0% duty cycle.
>
> analogWrite(127) means a signal of 50% duty cycle.
>
> analogWrite(255) means a signal of 100% duty cycle.
>
> On Arduino Uno, the PWM pins are 3, 5, 6, 9, 10 and 11. The frequency
> of PWM signal on pins 5 and 6 will be about 980Hz and on other pins
> will be 490Hz. The PWM pins are labeled with ~ sign.

[Here](https://www.instructables.com/Arduino-RC-Circuit-PWM-to-analog-DC/) is a tutorial on converting the PWM signal to an analog voltage level:

> The RC filter is a simple circuit element used to convert a pulsed
> signal to a flatter signal. The key concept is that the capacitor
> shunts the varying voltage to ground, producing a DC voltage.

Comment: Thank you for such comprehensive reply. Will look into it.

Comment: Any help Guys, please? I am Still stuck at the same point that how can i emulate Arduino as a joystick.